# Is it possible to rationalize a denominator containing two cube roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fractions, radicals

The fraction in question is

$$-\frac{12}{\sqrt[3]{12\sqrt{849} + 108} - \sqrt[3]{12\sqrt{849} - 108}}$$

And was reached in calculating the solution to $x^4 - x - 1 = 0$. I've tried all the standard methods, including $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$, but that doesn't work for cube roots, because once you have the square of one the two middle terms will not cancel each other out.

Comment: Have you thought about multiplying top and bottom by a²+ab+b² with a and b your cubed radicals? I am not saying it works, just a thought.

Comment: Since $ab = 110592$, that term would just serve to increase the fraction by a huge amount and do little good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As imranfat suggests in their comment, you should use the identity
$$
\frac1{\sqrt[3]a-\sqrt[3]b} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}}{a-b}
$$
which can be verified via cross-multiplication. In your case, take $a=12\sqrt{849} + 108$ and $b=12\sqrt{849} - 108$ and then work through simplifying the resulting expression. When I do so, I obtain
$$
-\frac{48+\left(12 \sqrt{849}-108\right)^{2/3}+\left(108+12 \sqrt{849}\right)^{2/3}}{18}.
$$

Comment: ...Which further simplifies to $-\frac{8 + \sqrt[3]{12\sqrt{849} + 620} + \sqrt[3]{12\sqrt{849} - 620}}{3}$.

Comment: Square each of $12\sqrt{849} \pm 108$, giving you single radicals. Then you can factor out 216 from each of them, place that in front as 6, and divide the whole fraction by six.